# I want to save a vim macro in my .vimrc?

Tags: vim, macros

I wrote a simple macro with vim and want to save this macro in a vimrc file.

I tried:

```
map <C-O> ^i<li>^[A</li>^[j

let @q='^i<li>^[A</li>^[j'
```

Both don't work. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a macro ready to go (via `qx` and used with `@x`) then you can write it to your vimrc from insert mode with `^Rx` or from normal mode with `"xp`. (Substitute your register for `x` in these examples.)

Comment: so if the macro is in register `t`, i.e. it can be played back with `@t`, then open your `.vimrc` and type `let @t=` then (while still in insert mode) hold `control`, press `r`, then let go of control and press `t`.

Comment: See this answer for an example: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31871/2721

Answer (score 1):

try this mapping:

```
nnoremap <c-o> ^i<li><esc>A</li><esc>j
```

Comment: @VitaliNeumann I suggest picking another short keys, `ctrl-o` is so useful for going back to previous jumplist position